# Mysql and money: precision problems with FLOAT(10,2)

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
mysql> describe transactions;
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cost                  | float(10,2)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I (naively?) thought that would be a good way to store amounts.
I am 3 days from release, and I discovered this:

```
mysql> UPDATE transactions SET cost = 162295.99 WHERE id = 14891;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from transactions where id = 14891;
+-------+---------------+
| id    | cost          |

+-------+---------------+
| 14891 |     162295.98 | 
+-------+---------------+
```

...?!? I entered .99, not .98!
So:

- Why is this doing it?
- How do I get out of this problem?
- Would decimal work? I tried with:

  mysql> alter table transactions modify cost decimal(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
  Query OK, 1120 rows affected, 119 warnings (0.14 sec)
  Records: 1120  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 119

  mysql>

However I am getting scary warnings. With "show warnings" I get:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                     |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'cost' at row 10  |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'cost' at row 369 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'cost' at row 371 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'cost' at row 378 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'cost' at row 402 |
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'cost' at row 403 |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------
```

- How do I see which one "row 10" is anyway?
- KEY QUESTION: How do I get out of this hole safely?
- (Rhetorical question bonus question) Why didn't this happen like 3 months ago, when fixing would have been easy?

Comment: The reason that your data shows up as .98 is that "The FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent **approximate** numeric data values" More on these datatypes here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: The _actual_ problem _in this case_ is that `FLOAT` has only 24 significant bits (about 7 significant digits).  That is not enough bits to distinguish between ...98 and ...99.  `DOUBLE`, with 53 bits, would "fix" that.  But _you should use `DECIMAL` for money_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Known problem with IEEE floats.  Use `DECIMAL`

To fix

- add new column of correct data type
- copy data over (check for conversion errors here)
- drop bad column
- rename new column to correct name

Why?  Murphy's Law.

Comment: Fantastic, problem solved, I can now release. Thanks!